# Diagonal text in diagonal matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices

I have a tridiagonal matrix whose diagonals `d_{-1}`, `d_0`, `d_1` (thought as vectors) can be written as vector expressions.

Is there a way to nicely represent this, e.g. via a matrix which is blank everywhere except from the diagonals which report the expression (written diagonally) and maybe continuous lines elsewhere?

(Please see the attached picture).

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this by setting up a matrix of math nodes in Tikz? I'll try and see how it goes for me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\begin{tabular}{c}
\rule[.5ex]{3em}{.5pt} $\exp_1(C)$   \rule[.5ex]{3em}{.5pt}\\
\rule[.5ex]{4em}{.5pt} $\exp_0(C)$   \rule[.5ex]{4em}{.5pt}\\
\rule[.5ex]{3em}{.5pt} $\exp_{-1}(C)$ \rule[.5ex]{3em}{.5pt}
\end{tabular}}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```